# Entity reparenting using pointers?

Tags: c++

In the game engine that I'm working on, I have a system of parenting entities to other entities. The way it works: Each entity has a pointer to its parent, and a vector of pointers to its children. In my editor, I want to have a feature were you can drag entities around a tree to reparent them. I already have dragging and dropping implemented, as well as a system to draw the tree of entities in my editor.

Question: How would I do the actual reparenting? Here's how the dragging and dropping looks:

```cpp
if (ImGuiPayload const* payload = ImGui::AcceptDragDropPayload("entity_reparent_id")) {
    int dragID = *static_cast<int*>(payload->Data);
    // do the reparenting
}
ImGui::EndDragDropTarget();
```

`childID` is the ID of the entity being dragged. (I have  a function to return a pointer to an entity by its ID)

So, I need to remove the entity from the previous parent's vector, and add it to the new parent's vector. I also need to make sure the entity isn't being reparented to a child, or a child of any of it's children. How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by writing an `IsDescendantOf()` method for your entity class, if you don't already have one:

```
bool Entity :: IsDescendantOf(const Entity * possibleAncestor) const
{
   const Entity * p = m_parent_ptr;
   while(p)
   {
      if (p == possibleAncestor) return true;
      p = p->m_parent_ptr;
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Once you have that, you can now call `proposedDestinationParentEntity->IsDescendantOf(draggedEntity)` to make sure that your reparenting operation won't end up creating a cycle in your tree.  If it returns true, stop and tell the user he can't do what he's trying to do.

Assuming the call returned false, then the actual reparenting is just a matter of removing the `draggedEntity` from its former-parent-node's children-list, adding it to the `proposedDestinationParentEntity` 's children-list, and changing `draggedEntity`'s `m_parent_ptr` to point to `proposedDestinationParentEntity`.